# Node js ACL export issue

Tags: node.js, node-acl

I have recently started development of a Node js application with user authentication and authorization. I have successfully implemented the user authentication with passport js but having an issue with the user authorization using node acl.

**security.js** file looks like this

```
var node_acl = require('acl'),
    acl;
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/claim_app', function (err, db) {
    var mongoBackend = new node_acl.mongodbBackend(db, 'acl');
    acl = new node_acl(mongoBackend);
    console.log(acl);
    set_roles();
});

function set_roles() {

    acl.allow([{
        roles: 'admin',
        allows: [{
            resources: '/api/conf',
            permissions: '*'
        }
        ]
    }, {
        roles: 'user',
        allows: [{
            resources: 'photos',
            permissions: ['view', 'edit', 'delete']
        }]
    }, {
        roles: 'guest',
        allows: []
    }]);
}
module.exports = acl;
```

but when I try to use above with **require('./src/config/security')**, always getting as undefined. what is the reason for this behaviour.

Thanks.

Comment: Your ```acl``` is undefined when you export it since it is asynchronously set in the ```.connect```

Comment: @Wainage Is there a way to fix that issue? I want to use this `acl` in routes.

Comment: Answer is more complex than you think. Wrap ```acl``` in a function if you call poll results or wrap the connect in a Promise which is exported

Comment: I am facing the same issue. If you were able to achieve it, please share the answer.

Comment: No, I didn't have enough time to  look it again since it was an R&D work.